# driver is failing to switch to default content

Tags: python, selenium

So I am able to send keys to the input box in the iframe but my script fails once it gets to `driver.switch.to.default_content()`

```
try: 
    # iframe/textbox 
    iframe = driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[4]/div/nz-modal-container/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/nz-form-item[1]/nz-form-control/div/div/app-richtext/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/iframe")
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element(By. XPATH, "/html/body/p").send_keys('Test')
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
   
    
    #....
    driver.find_element(By. CSS_SELECTOR, "#cdk-overlay-9 > nz-modal-container > div > div > div.ant-modal-footer.ng-tns-c101-267.ng-star-inserted > button.ant-btn.orange.ant-btn-primary.ng-star-inserted").click()
```

the iframe is nested in a div, but the div is inside of the body tag so I do not understand why it keeps failing.

```
<div class="tox-sidebar-wrap"><div class="tox-edit-area"><iframe id="tinymceEditor25143_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-0 for help." class="tox-edit-area__iframe" cd_frame_id_="e4e847880825311ca786ccd99c5e96d0"></iframe></div><div role="complementary" class="tox-sidebar"><div data-alloy-tabstop="true" tabindex="-1" class="tox-sidebar__slider tox-sidebar--sliding-closed" style="width: 0px;"><div class="tox-sidebar__pane-container"></div></div></div></div>
<div class="tox-edit-area"><iframe id="tinymceEditor25143_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-0 for help." class="tox-edit-area__iframe" cd_frame_id_="e4e847880825311ca786ccd99c5e96d0"></iframe></div>
        

<iframe id="tinymceEditor25143_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-0 for help." class="tox-edit-area__iframe" cd_frame_id_="e4e847880825311ca786ccd99c5e96d0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you confirm the url?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: what mean `fails`? We can't run your code, and we can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: maybe first run without `try/except` to see full errors.

Comment: sorry, was more of a general question to see if anyone had similar issues in similar circumstances. I would share the site but you won't be able to view the page due to you needing certain credentials.